# How do I delete Google plus pictures from my profile?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

Is there a way I can delete all my Google+ pictures?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot delete all your photos in one action. You have to delete them album by album.

1. Sign in to your [Google account](http://accounts.google.com)
2. Go to [Picasa Web Albums](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/myphotos)

   You may have to click through if you see "Click here to go back to Picasa Web Albums." appear
3. Click and open an album
4. Select **Actions → Delete album**
5. Do this for each album you want to delete.

This will also remove those from your linked Android phone.

The only way to delete all your photos in one go is to delete both Picasa and Google+ accounts.

Comment: note that this answer doesn't really delete all your photos, just the photos from one album

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to delete each individual photo.

1. Open up your Google+ Profile.
2. Click on your profile photo to open the photo slider.
3. Move your mouse around.
4. Click the trash can that appears in the slider's upper right hand corner.

This method deletes the little photo icon options in your Gmail as well.